# Unity for 2D games

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, quartz-graphics

Ignoring price for the moment, would using Unity for a 2D game be better than building one natively in iOS, i.e. faster and more powerful because of the underlying OpenGL usage, or is it either not supported well, complete overkill, not much better than just using UIImages and/or Quartz, or for some other reason worse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the game. If you have under 100 or so sprites, you can just use UIViews without any big issue. Over that and you're starting to get in the realm where OpenGL will matter.

If I were doing a game with with lots of sprites or particles, I'd certainly look into Unity. Then again, I'd also look into Cocos2D. (I'm not directly familiar with either, my games are all UIView-based.)

Comment: Would you mind shamelessly plugging those games so I can take a look at how involved they are? :)

Comment: King of Dragon Pass and Jigami.

Answer (score 1):

Building any game using Unity instead of just UIKit/Quartz has the advantage that it will be easier to port it to other platforms if you want to.